# Does terraform support the concept of an include directive?

Tags: terraform

I would like to include a global .tfvars file in a product specific .tfvars file. e.g.

```
global.tfvars
  region = "us-east-1"
  availability_zone = "us-east-1a"

foo.tfvars
  include 'global.tfvars'
  instance_type = "t2.medium"
  ...
```

That said, I realize that I could use 2 -var-file parameters (as documented [here](https://www.terraform.io/intro/getting-started/variables.html)) but that is not precisely what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can quite do that very easily in stock terraform.  Check out the terragrunt project.  With it you can define global variables that descend into sub modules.

https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terragrunt